# sql group by last status change

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have a table which store log information (mainly status changes)

The table is something like this:

```
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id | number |  status  |      timestamp      |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 |     25 | buffered | 2012-05-05 23:10:10 |
|  2 |     25 | sent     | 2012-05-05 23:10:11 |
|  3 |     26 | not sent | 2012-05-05 23:10:12 |
|  4 |     27 | buffered | 2012-05-05 23:10:13 |
+----+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

I need to generate a report by status. but the status for a number can change.

The status for a number can begin with `buffered` and later change to `sent` or `not sent`

Or can begin with `sent` or `not sent` and in this case, the status won't change anymore

I think that with these conditions that I can group by by either `sent` or `not sent` without problems (Is this correct?)

But how can I generate the report for only `buffered` rows?

In this particular sample, if I get asked: What numbers are buffered the correct answer is: `number 27`

P.D.

I think the title does not reflect the question accurately, if anyone has a better title feel free to change it.

Comment: what about `where` clause: `where status = 'buffered'` ? Are you talking about buffered rows that don't has a sent or not sent row for it number?

Comment: Exactly, I need the numbers who only has status buffered, in this case number 25 should not appear as buffered because it later got sent.

Comment: ok, I have published my answer with your requirements. bye.

Comment: Any of these answers helps you? Remember to select the correct one please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the query (with out subqueries for better performance):

```
select distinct
    l1.id,  l1.number, l1.status, l1.timestamp 
from 
    my_logs l1 
 left outer joing
    my_logs l2
        on l1.number = l2.number and l2.status <> 'buffered'
where 
    l1.status = 'buffered' and
    l2.number is null
```

**Explanation:**

Join your table with itself by number key. Second time, table only take rows with value different than 'buffered'. If a row is found in 'second' table, then it means that they are values differents than 'buffered' with this number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is 'log_table', this should provide you the latest status for the given number:

```
 SELECT number, status FROM log_table  AS l WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
              FROM log_table WHERE number = l.number);
```

**One of my Big Wishes for MYSQL** would be for it to allow (but it doesn't currently support):

```
SELECT number, status FROM log_table GROUP BY number HAVING MAX(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT number, status FROM YOUR_TABLE t1 WHERE status  = :someStatus and NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM YOUR_TABLE t2 WHERE t1.id<>t2.id and t1.number = t2.number and t2.timestamp>t1.timestamp)
```

Please ensure that number and timestamp fields contains the appropiate index created to guarantee performance on your query.

Answer (score 0):

Group all status in the order they appear and select only those that starts and ends in status buffered (has has only status: buffered)

```
Select number, group_concat(status) allstatus 
from tablename
 group by number
 having allstatus regexp '^buffered$'
 order by timestamp
```